# Simple play/pause CSS animation button with switching icon

Tags: javascript, html, css

Could anyone help me by adding a simple play/pause button to my text scrolling animation?. I need the button to work as an icon only using `<i class="fa-regular fa-circle-play"></i>` and `<i class="fa-regular fa-circle-pause"></i>` but display only one icon at a time according to the animation state.

I'm using the js code for flipping from @guradio

```js
// for selecting the input field on clicking over the flip text 
    function selectText() {
      const input = document.getElementById('searchInput');
      input.focus();
      input.select();
    }

// for flipping the text
    $('#searchInput').keyup(function() {
      if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $('#text-flip').show();
      } else {        
        $('#text-flip').hide();
      }
    }).keyup();
```

```css
        #text-flip {
        height:20px;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin-top: -20px;
        }

        #text-flip > div > div {
        color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
        padding-left: 60px;
        height:45px;
        margin-bottom:45px;
        display:inline-block;
        font-size: inherit
        }

        #text-flip div:first-child {
        animation: show 10s linear infinite;
        }
            
        @keyframes show {
        0% {margin-top:-270px;}
        5% {margin-top:-180px;}
        33% {margin-top:-180px;}
        38% {margin-top:-90px;}
        66% {margin-top:-90px;}
        71% {margin-top:0px;}
        99.99% {margin-top:0px;}
        100% {margin-top:-270px;}        
        }
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <form action="#" method="get">        
      <input id="searchInput" placeholder="Search: "/>

      <div id="text-flip" onclick="selectText()">
          <div><div>Third Text</div></div>
          <div><div>Second Text</div></div>
          <div><div>First Text</div></div>
      </div>        
  </form>
```

Comment: No idea why you thought to animate the user's selection. Lose that ux functionality and problem sovled.

Comment: @GetSet I need this effect for my search bar with top searched item names to scroll like a input placeholder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your code.

```js
let isPlayed=true;
    
// for flipping the text
$('#searchInput').keyup(function() {
      if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $('#text-flip').show();
      } else {        
        $('#text-flip').hide();
      }
    }).keyup();
function btnClicked() {
    if(isPlayed)
       $(".controlBtn").html("<i class='fa-solid fa-circle-play' onclick='btnClicked()'></i>");
    else
       $(".controlBtn").html("<i class='fa-solid fa-circle-pause' onclick='btnClicked()'></i>");
    $("#text-flip div:first-child").toggleClass("flip-animation");
    isPlayed = !isPlayed;
 }
 function selectText() {
    const input = document.getElementById('searchInput');
    input.focus();
    input.select();
 }
```

```css
#text-flip {
        height:20px;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin-top: -20px;
        }

        #text-flip > div > div {
            color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
            padding-left: 60px;
            height:45px;
            margin-bottom:45px;
            display:inline-block;
            font-size: inherit
        }

        #text-flip div:first-child {
            animation: show 10s linear infinite;
        }
            
        @keyframes show {
           0% {margin-top:-270px;}
           5% {margin-top:-180px;}
           33% {margin-top:-180px;}
           38% {margin-top:-90px;}
           66% {margin-top:-90px;}
           71% {margin-top:0px;}
           99.99% {margin-top:0px;}
           100% {margin-top:-270px;}        
        }
        .controlBtn {
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        #text-flip div.flip-animation:first-child {
            animation-play-state: paused !important;
         }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-9usAa10IRO0HhonpyAIVpjrylPvoDwiPUiKdWk5t3PyolY1cOd4DSE0Ga+ri4AuTroPR5aQvXU9xC6qOPnzFeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <form action="#" method="get">        
      <input id="searchInput" placeholder="Search: "/>

      <div id="text-flip" class="flip-animation" onclick="selectText()">
          <div><div>Third Text</div></div>
          <div><div>Second Text</div></div>
          <div><div>First Text</div></div>
      </div>        
  </form>
  <div class="controlBtn"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-pause" onclick="btnClicked()"></i></div>
```

Comment: every time I pause the flipping it stops at the "Third Text" always, is there anyway to pause it as where it is and play it from the same position? no matter if it's in the middle of first and second text or whatever.

Comment: I updated snippet according to your requirements.